# Command npm install fails due to node-libcurl

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, ubuntu-17.10, node-libcurl

When doing `npm install` it fails due to node-libcurl. I have it succesfully working on MacOSX but on my ubuntu box it is not working. Any suggestions on what is going wrong and what I can do to fix it.

Node.js Version: v9.4.0
NPM Version: 5.6.0
Ubuntu 17.10

```
> node-libcurl@1.3.0 install /root/hs2-homework/Bot/node_modules/node-libcurl
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://github.com/JCMais/node-libcurl/releases/download/v1.3.0/node_libcurl-v1.3.0-node-v59-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for node-libcurl@1.3.0 and node@9.4.0 (node-v59 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py", line 13, in <module>
    import gyp
  File "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import gyp.input
  File "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 5, in <module>
    from compiler.ast import Const
ImportError: No module named compiler.ast
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:336:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:160:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.13.0-25-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/root/hs2-homework/Bot/node_modules/node-libcurl/lib/binding/node_libcurl.node" "--module_name=node_libcurl" "--module_path=/root/hs2-homework/Bot/node_modules/node-libcurl/lib/binding"
gyp ERR! cwd /root/hs2-homework/Bot/node_modules/node-libcurl
gyp ERR! node -v v9.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/root/hs2-homework/Bot/node_modules/node-libcurl/lib/binding/node_libcurl.node --module_name=node_libcurl --module_path=/root/hs2-homework/Bot/node_modules/node-libcurl/lib/binding' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/root/hs2-homework/Bot/node_modules/node-libcurl/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:160:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.13.0-25-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/root/hs2-homework/Bot/node_modules/node-libcurl/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /root/hs2-homework/Bot/node_modules/node-libcurl
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v9.4.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/root/hs2-homework/Bot/node_modules/node-libcurl/lib/binding/node_libcurl.node --module_name=node_libcurl --module_path=/root/hs2-homework/Bot/node_modules/node-libcurl/lib/binding' (1)
npm WARN discord.js@11.2.1 requires a peer of bufferutil@^3.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.2.1 requires a peer of erlpack@hammerandchisel/erlpack but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.2.1 requires a peer of node-opus@^0.2.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.2.1 requires a peer of opusscript@^0.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.2.1 requires a peer of sodium@^2.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.2.1 requires a peer of libsodium-wrappers@^0.5.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.2.1 requires a peer of uws@^0.14.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN Bot No description
npm WARN Bot No repository field.
npm WARN Bot No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-libcurl@1.3.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-libcurl@1.3.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-01-28T18_51_21_983Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After scrounging the depths of the internet I found what was happening. My python library was not updated causing the installation to fail. I updated python by itself **not** using `sudo apt-get upgrade` but `sudo apt-get update python`.